# How to pass Python Fabric Task Variable into another Function or Task

Tags: python, task, fabric

I hope someone could help me with this problem I am having. So it looks pretty simple, I just wanted to get the variable that was set inside a Fabric task and wanted it to be called in another function. Global Variable seems to not work and I am relatively new to python fabric so any help would be appreciated.

```
from fabric.api import *
@task
def function_inside(name):

    samplename = name.lower()
    print("{}".format(samplename))


def another_function():
      print "This is outside: " + samplename 

another_funtion()
```

So after much time working on this primer script that I have, I just have a workaround.

`from fabric.api import *
  container={A:'',B:''}`

```
@task
def first_func(var):
    container['A']=var
@task
def second_func(var):
    container['B']=var
@task
def main_func():
    var1=container['A']
    var2=container['B']
    print "This is from first function: " + var1
    print "This is from second function: " + var2
```

so when I execute the fabric it goes like this:

```
fab firs_func:John second_func:Angel main_func
```

But this is still a workaround and I would still like to know how we can call a variable from a task and pass it to a normal function that is not a tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about fabric but i can help you for global variable

**try this:-**

```
def function_inside(name):
    global samplename
    samplename = name.lower()
    print("{}".format(samplename))


def another_function():
      print ("This is outside: " + samplename)

#execute as below
function_inside("HELLO")
another_function()
```

Comment: the code you gave me is good for normal functions, I tried it as well but seems like it is a different case with python fabric tasks. global variable is not working (weird). anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add your "global" variable in Fabric's `env` dictionary. This dictionary has its state kept during your Python script's lifecycle. Given that, your code would look like:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.tasks import execute #The 'execute' function is quite useful
                                  when you want to tell Fabric to execute a
                                  function as a Fabric task

#No need to annotate your function
def function_inside(name):

    env.samplename = name.lower()
    print("{}".format(env.samplename))


def another_function():
      print "This is outside: " + env.samplename

execute(function_inside, "Foo")
execute(another_function)
```

And then, in your shell:

```
python your_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

What about running tasks synchronously and wait for the result?

```
# @task
def first_func(var):
    # process var
    return var
# @task
def second_func(var):
    # process var
    return var
@task
def main_func():
    var1=first_func(container['A'])
    # or var1=first_func(var1)
    var2=second_func(container['B'])
    # or var2=first_func(var2)
    print "This is from first function: " + var1
    print "This is from second function: " + var2
```